# How to (easily) put python variables from Django into html?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, variables

In one of my Django projects in views.py I've got some code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *

# Create your views here.

products = Product.objects.all()
product_list = list(products)

def displayhome(request):
    return render(request, 'bootstrap/index.html', {'title': product_list[0].title}, {'link': product_list[0].official_path_name})
```

Now using this (very clunky) method, I am able to put the string version of variables into html using:

```
{{title}}
```

for example. However this does not let me operate on the variables, e.g. if I sent through `product_list` I couldn't get `product_list[0]`. I vaguely know of using `{% %}` tags instead of `{{ }}` but I am (a) not completely sure how they work and (b) don't know how powerful they are e.g. if you could use it like a normal python file.

How would I use a variable from python (say it is an integer with value 4) to create a variable number of html elements (e.g. 4 boxes) for example?

If there is no easy way to execute python in html, is there a way to instead put my python variables into javascript and then somehow use those in the html instead?

Comment: Rule of the thumb: any excessive logic should not be done in template but in the view. Anyway - accessing properties/values in templates is done via `.` operator, no matter what datastructure it is, so what you want is `product_list.0`

Comment: Read about [Variables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/#variables) in the Django documentation. If you want to access `product_list[0]` in the template you have to write it as `{{ product_list.0 }}`.

Comment: Is there an easier way to add multiple variables at once to a template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this structure for my views:

```
def your_view(request):
    myResult = MODEL_NAME.objects.all()

    context = {
            "variable1":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
            "variable2":"This is the variable 2",
            "variable3":"This is the variable 3",
            "variable4":myResult
            }
    return render(request, 'your_html.html', context)
```

and you can access the variables in the template like this

```html
<!-- See variables by index   -->
{{ variable1.0 }}
{{ variable1.2 }}

<!-- Iterate over variables -->
{% for x in variable1 %}
      {{ x }}
{% endfor %}

<!-- Variable 2 & 3 -->
{{ variable2 }}
{{ variable3 }}

<!-- Query set result -->
{% for x in variable4 %}
      {{ x.id }}
      {{ x.name }} <!-- and all the other values from your model -->
{% endfor %}
```